# How do i deploy from a single github repo with multiple branches to multiple AppHarbor instances

Tags: github, appharbor

I have a private repository on GitHub that contains an ASP.Net MVC project and am able to deploy this via a Service hook to my AppHarbor instance.

My repository contains three branches, Develop, Test and Release.

How do i configure separate instances to each receive a different branch of my repository?

I have found the setting in AppHarbor to specify which branch is being tracked and can perform a Test or Release branch deployment to an individual instance successfully.

What i cant figure out is how to configure my one repository to deploy to three different AppHarbor instances like below. It appears that when administering my GibHub repository I can only configure a single Service Hook.

**GitHub Repo / Branch -> AppHarbor instance**

MyProject/Release -> MyProject_Release.AppHb.com

MyProject/Test -> MyProject_Test.AppHb.com

MyProject/Develop -> MyProject_Develop.AppHb.com

I case this is relevant, I intend on purchasing a AppHarbor "Catamaran" account for the release site and use the free 'Canoe' accounts for testing and development branches.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can supply a comma-seperated list of "Application slugs" when configuring the appharbor service hook.

> application_slug" is a list of unique application identifiers
>   delimited by "," (i.e. "foo" or "foo,bar") that pushes should trigger
>   builds on.

MyProject_Release, MyProject_Test, MyProject_Develop